# Firestore write not working although security rules are set correctly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have set up the following security rule, because I only want Admins to be able to write to the collection enums:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /enums/{test}/ {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
    }
```

When I am trying to write from the client I get the following error:
`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: PERMISSION_DENIED: No matching allow statements` although the `request.auth.token.admin` is set to true, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I don't want to modify this: `allow write: if true;` because I am trying to develop some production ready rules.

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the greatest mistake of all time here guys... a typo.
My collection should be called `enum` instead of `enums`. It took me several days to find this out.

PS: Firebase is amazing :-)

Comment: Good to hear you found the source of the problem Christian. I voted to close your question as a typo, since it's unlikely that others in the same situation will find it.